# R applying a user-defined function to each row of a column

Tags: r, apply

I have a dataframe containing uniprot accession and IDs like this:

```
> a <- data.frame(protein=c("sp|A6NCE7|MP3B2_HUMAN,sp|Q9GZQ8|MLP3B_HUMAN","sp|A6NL28|TPM3L_HUMAN","sp|B5ME19|EIFCL_HUMAN,sp|Q99613|EIF3C_HUMAN"),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
> a
                                      protein
1 sp|A6NCE7|MP3B2_HUMAN,sp|Q9GZQ8|MLP3B_HUMAN
2                       sp|A6NL28|TPM3L_HUMAN
3 sp|B5ME19|EIFCL_HUMAN,sp|Q99613|EIF3C_HUMAN
```

Now, I wrote a function for splitting a each of the strings into usable parts:

```
split.uniprot.string <- function(uniprot_string){
  first.protein <- unlist(strsplit(uniprot_string,"[,]"))[1]
  uniprot_accession <- unlist(strsplit(first.protein,"[|]"))[2]
  uniprot_ID <- unlist(strsplit(first.protein,"[|]"))[3]
  list(uniprot_ID=uniprot_ID, uniprot_accession=uniprot_accession)
}
```

It works fine, if I apply it to single rows:

```
> split.uniprot.string(a$protein[2])
$uniprot_ID
[1] "TPM3L_HUMAN"

$uniprot_accession
[1] "A6NL28"
```

However, if I try to apply it to each row of the dataframe, the function is somehow only applied to the first line correctly (the same happens, if I run a FOR-loop on each row):

```
> a$uniprot_ID <- apply(a,1,function(row) split.uniprot.string(a$protein)$uniprot_ID)
> a
                                      protein  uniprot_ID
1 sp|A6NCE7|MP3B2_HUMAN,sp|Q9GZQ8|MLP3B_HUMAN MP3B2_HUMAN
2                       sp|A6NL28|TPM3L_HUMAN MP3B2_HUMAN
3 sp|B5ME19|EIFCL_HUMAN,sp|Q99613|EIF3C_HUMAN MP3B2_HUMAN
```

What do I have to change, so that the function fills in the correct uniprot_ID in each row (i.e. "TPM3L_HUMAN" in row 2 and "EIF3C_HUMAN" in row 3)?

Comment: `function(row) split.uniprot.string(a$protein)$uniprot_ID`: you have to change `a` to `row` as it is your function's variable... (and you cannot use `$protein` etc. as `row` is a `vector`)

Comment: Just for completeness: the example table had only one column. If you apply the function on more than one column, you have to add the column index to row, i.e. function(row) split.uniprot.string(row['column-index']).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are complicated a bit your problem (besides the "typo").

As I understand it, you are interested in the last part of the first "sequence", the one after the last `|`?

If so, you can do:

```
a$uniprot_ID <- gsub("^sp\\|{1}[^|]+\\|{1}([^|,]+)($|,.*)","\\1",a$protein)

a
#                                      protein  uniprot_ID
#1 sp|A6NCE7|MP3B2_HUMAN,sp|Q9GZQ8|MLP3B_HUMAN MP3B2_HUMAN
#2                       sp|A6NL28|TPM3L_HUMAN TPM3L_HUMAN
#3 sp|B5ME19|EIFCL_HUMAN,sp|Q99613|EIF3C_HUMAN EIFCL_HUMAN
```

and if you also want the part after the first `|` for the first "sequence" (in case of a comma), you can do:

```
a$uniprot_accession <- gsub("^sp\\|{1}([^|]+).*","\\1",a$protein)

a
#                                      protein  uniprot_ID uniprot_accession
#1 sp|A6NCE7|MP3B2_HUMAN,sp|Q9GZQ8|MLP3B_HUMAN MP3B2_HUMAN            A6NCE7
#2                       sp|A6NL28|TPM3L_HUMAN TPM3L_HUMAN            A6NL28
#3 sp|B5ME19|EIFCL_HUMAN,sp|Q99613|EIF3C_HUMAN EIFCL_HUMAN            B5ME19
```

Comment: @Flo, you're welcome :-), `gsub` is very practical to replace something in a string by something else but can also be used, like here, to extract a part of a string

Comment: Though, looking at your code, I am not sure which approach is more complicated :-)

Comment: @Flo, I thought you might say that... ;-)